# How to click a button on a website?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I'm trying to click a certain button on a website. Here is it's code.

```
<div id="ff_submit_button">


<input type="image" onclick="javascript:return preFareFinderSubmitActions('The following information is needed to process your request:', 'Problem Pricing the Itinerary: Atlantic City Express Service offers adult fares only for all passengers.  Please modify your selection to continue. \n[Error ID: 1121S]')" src="/images/en/btn_ff_go.gif" alt="Click to Find Tickets" border="0" name="_handler=url.presentation.handler.request.rail.urlRailSearchRequestHandler/_xpath=/sessionWorkflow/productWorkflow[@product='Rail']">

</div>
```

At the moment, I have it hitting the "alt="Click to find tickets" with this code in a button.

```
    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("alt") = "Click to Find Tickets" Then
            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")

        End If
```

It works, but the problem is that there is another area on the website that also uses that alt. Thus it's asking to enter a username and password. My line of code is in a button at the moment.

Comment: I don't get the actual problem in your question

Comment: Check the value of the src attribute as well as the alt

Comment: Robuust, the problem is I'm trying to make it click that line of code more specifically since there are other fields with the same alt causing me to get messages.

Tim, would I include src in like If webpageelement.GetAttribute("alt, src") = "Click to Find Tickets, /images/en/btn_ff_go.gif" Then
            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")

I suspect I'd be doing that wrong then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `alt`, the better element to check for would be `id` - this is [meant to provide a unique identifier](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/id), although you'd need to add it to your input tag.

Comment: I tried putting id before hand, but it just doesn't work for some reason. Thus I went ahead and tried alt instead.